# How to do multiple transactions in python loops

Tags: python

How can I change this code

```
e_code = input("Please enter your purchase history: ")
e_codelist = e_code.split(";")

balance = 0
for codes in e_codelist:
  unit = codes.split(":")
  unit_v = unit[1]
 
  if float(unit_v) > 0:
    print(unit[1],unit[0], "bought")
    balance = 
  elif float(unit_v) < 0:
    print(unit[1],unit[0], "sold")
```

For example,

```
Please enter your purchase history: SUC:0.2;ETR:1.2;SUC:-0.3;SUC:0.3;ETR:2;ETR:-1.1
0.2 SUC bought
1.2 ETR bought
-0.3 SUC sold
0.3 SUC bought
2 ETR bought
-1.1 ETR sold
How can I change this into
0.2 SUC bought
1.2 ETR bought
Not enough SUC
0.3 SUC bought
2.0 ETR bought
1.1 ETR sold
```

Comment: Please fix your code's syntax errors.

Comment: do you want something like this `{'SUC': 0.2, 'ETR': 2.1}` as balance? Considering these are different things?

Comment: explain clearly what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My sugestion is using dictionary to track the current balance of different items

and in every transaction if it's buy then buy

but if it's sell check whether you have enough quantity

```
e_code = input("Please enter your purchase history: ")
e_codelist = e_code.split(";")

balance = {i.split(":")[0]:0 for i in e_codelist} # starting with 0 for all possible items
for codes in e_codelist:
  unit = codes.split(":")
  unit_v = float(unit[1]) # converting value to float
 
  if unit_v > 0: # buying
    print(unit[1],unit[0], "bought")
    balance[unit[0]]+=unit_v
  elif unit_v < 0: # selling
    if balance[unit[0]]<-unit_v: # checking if I can sell
      print(f"Not enough {unit[0]}")
    else:
      print(-unit_v,unit[0], "sold")
      balance[unit[0]]+=unit_v
```

```
Please enter your purchase history: SUC:0.2;ETR:1.2;SUC:-0.3;SUC:0.3;ETR:2;ETR:-1.1
0.2 SUC bought
1.2 ETR bought
Not enough SUC
0.3 SUC bought
2 ETR bought
1.1 ETR sold
```

To have more clarity I would suggest you print the `balance` dictionary.

Using dictionary allows you to have as many different items you want